# Alterar visibilidade de layout xml com a mudança de orientação do aparelho

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Estou precisando alterar a visibilidade de um layout no xml quando a orientação do dispositivo for de portrait (em pé) para landscape (deitado). Pretendo adicionar 2 colunas ao executar esta ação. Utilizei o código `android:visibility="gone"` para esconder, porém não estou conseguindo encontrar a forma de mudar para `android:visibility="visibility"` quando a orientação for alterada.

Segue código completo abaixo.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:visibility="gone">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnPer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/button_green"
      android:text="@string/Btn_Per"
      android:textColor="@color/gray"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnQuad"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/button_green"
      android:text="@string/Btn_Quad"
      android:textColor="@color/gray"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnRaiz"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/button_green"
      android:text="@string/Btn_Raiz"
      android:textColor="@color/gray"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnUm"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/button_green"
      android:text="@string/Btn_Um"
      android:textColor="@color/gray"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnMod"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/button_green"
      android:text="@string/Btn_Mod"
      android:textColor="@color/gray"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione `android:configChanges="orientation"` no seu manifest da activity assim:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloAndroid"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Depois faça um override no `onConfigurationChanged` assim:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);,
        int orientation=newConfig.orientation;

        switch(orientation) {

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
         //faça alguma coisa quando mudar pra landscape

        break;

       case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
             //faça alguma coisa quando mudar pra potrait

       break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A abordagem recomendada para lidar com essa necessidade é construir um *layout* diferente para cada orientação do dispositivo.

O Android permite utilizar [qualificadores de configuração](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) para nomear pastas de recursos de forma a permitir seleccionar os recursos a usar de acordo com a configuração do dispositivo.

Crie duas pasta dentro da pasta `/res`, uma chamada `layout-land` e outra chamada `layout-port`.
Na primeira coloque o *layout* que quer que seja apresentado quando o dispositivo se encontre na posição *landscape* e na segunda o *layout* para a posição *portraint*.

O Android escolherá automaticamente o *layout* a utilizar em cada uma das configurações.